# How inplace attribute works in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
s=pd.Series(data=[45,20,35,50,60],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
s.drop("a",inplace=False)
print(s)
a    45
b    20
c    35
d    50
e    60
dtype: int64

s.drop("a",inplace=True)
    b    20
    c    35
    d    50
    e    60
    dtype: int64
```

when i am changing the value of inplace attribute to False, element at index "a" not deleted but when i am changing the value of inplace = True value at index "a" deleted. I did not understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `drop` with `inplace=False`, `drop` is returning a new Series rather than dropping the requested row in the existing Series.  In other words:

```
x = s.drop("a",inplace=False)
print(s)
print()
print(x)
```

produces:

```
a    45
b    20
c    35
d    50
e    60
dtype: int64

b    20
c    35
d    50
e    60
dtype: int64
```

where:

```
x = s.drop("a",inplace=True)
print(s)
print()
print(x)
```

produces:

```
b    20
c    35
d    50
e    60
dtype: int64

None
```